# Draw Gizmos Axis on Hololens

Tags: hololens

i use Hololens and when I move the object or rotate I should show the axes.  The code to move or rotate the object I already have it and in the editor the gizmo asxis are seen, but on the hololens emulator no.

Can you help me? thank you so much

Comment: How can you say "it should show the axes"? Improve your question by answering that

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but is it right to say you have a manipulatable hololens object working and you just want to show the X/Y/Z axes like the unity editor does?

The axis you see is just a gizmo to help show orientation while in the scene view.  It will disappear in the Game view, or any emulator/actual build to a device.  It's not an easy approach to try to make that axis itself appear in your finished game.

Instead, to show an axis, you just need to create your own 3D model of an axis, and attach it as a child to the gameobject you are moving/rotating.

You can enable or disable the axis gameobject if you want it to only appear while moving.  Treat it just like any other Unity GameObject, the intro tutorials will show you how to do that.

Good Luck!